# Write a method to replace all spaces in a string with '%20'?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I have a question about a programming problem from the book Cracking The Code Interview by Gayl Laakmann McDowell, 5th Edition.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my answer? It varies a lot from the answer given in the book.

```
public String replace(String str){

   String[] words = str.split(" ");
   StringBuffer sentence = new StringBuffer();

   for(String w: words){
      sentence.append("%20");
      sentence.append(w);
   }

  return sentence.toString();
}
```

Comment: Varies as in it gives the wrong result? Or varies as in this is a correct answer but different from the one in the book?

Comment: This should have just worked, please specify how it didn't work, `replaceAll(" ", "%20");` will replace all single space to `%20` but if you are doing it to encode URL take a look at URLEncoder

Comment: `sentence = sentence.replace(" ", "%20");`?

Comment: @arynaq In that it is not the answer from the book (and incorrect) and the book answer is way more complicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007631/write-a-method-to-replace-all-spaces-in-a-string-with-20

Comment: Your sentence will start with "%20".

Comment: Well, `"a b"` would be `"%20a%20b"`, I wonder why is that not correct? Mhhh ...

Comment: @Tom because the sentence starts with a "%20"

Comment: @JigarJoshi I don't think that OP can use existing methods if he should implement that himself.

Comment: @Opal So you already know, why your answer is wrong? Then what is the purpose of this question? Btw: you should train your sarcasm detector.

Comment: Strange interview question. The correct answer in most cases would be to construct a `URI`, which does this conversion automaticaly.

Comment: I found out why because @TilmanHausherr clarified for me.

Comment: Oh ok. It sounded like you already knew that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this loop, the program adds `%20` before each word:

> ```
>    for(String w: words){
>       sentence.append("%20");
>       sentence.append(w);
>    }
> ```

That will produce incorrect results, for example for `a b` it will give `%20a%20b`.

There's a much simpler solution:

```
public String replace(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
}
```

Or, if you really don't want to use `.replaceAll`, then write like this:

```
public String replace(String str) {
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder(words[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < words.length; ++i) {
        sentence.append("%20");
        sentence.append(words[i]);
    }

    return sentence.toString();
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit late but using `str.replace` is preferred over `replaceAll` as the latter one compiles the regex pattern and then matches and that is why it is slower and not preferred for simple substitutions like whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

Question in the book says:

> Note: if implementing in Java, please use a character array so that
>   you can perform this operation in place.

It also says that the char array that you get as input is long enough to hold the modified string.
By using `split` and `StringBuffer` you use additional O(n) space. That's why your answer varies a lot and is incorrect (apart from adding additional `"%20"`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following, which replaces any space

```
String s = "Hello this is a       string!";
System.out.println(replaceSpace(s, "%20"));


public static String replaceSpace(String s, String replacement) {
    String ret = s.replaceAll("  *", replacement);
    return ret;
}
```

Gives

```
Hello%20this%20is%20a%20string!
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest way:

```
public void replaceAll( String str )
{
    String temp = str.trim();

    char[] arr = temp.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
    {
        if( arr[i] == ' ' )
        {
            sb.append( "%20" );
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append( arr[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String applyReplaceOperationWithCount(String str) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(str)) { //if string is null or empty, return it
        return str;
    }
    char[] strChar = str.toCharArray(); 

    int count = 0; //count spaces in the string to recalculate the array length
    for (char c : strChar) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count == 0) { // if there are no spaces in the string, return it 
        return str;
    }

    int length = strChar.length;
    char[] newChar = new char[length + (count * 2)]; // 1 char will be replaced by 3 chars. So the new length should be count*2 larger than original
    int index = 0;
    for (char c : strChar) { 
        if (c != ' ') { // if char is not a space just push it in the next available location
            newChar[index++] = c;
        } else { // if char is a space just push %,2,0 
            newChar[index++] = '%';
            newChar[index++] = '2';
            newChar[index++] = '0';
        }
    }
    return new String(newChar); // convert the new array into string
}
```

Comment: Answers should always come with a bit of explanation, so if you could add that, it would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am using `matches` and `replaceAll` it works well.

```
public class ReplaceSpaces {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = " Abcd olmp  thv ";

    if(text.matches(".*\\s+.*")){
        System.out.println("Yes I see white space and I am replacing it");
        String newText = text.replaceAll("\\s+", "%20");
        System.out.println(newText);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Nope I dont see white spaces");
    }
}
}
```

Output
`Yes I see white space and I am replacing it`
`%20Abcd%20olmp%20thv%20`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String replaceSpaceInString(String string,String toreplace){
    String replacedString = "";
    if(string.isEmpty()) return string;
    string = string.trim();
    if(string.indexOf(" ") == -1)return string;
    else{
        replacedString = string.replaceAll("\\s+",toreplace);
    }
    return replacedString;
}
```